# Adding a default front page to Reporting Services 2014

Tags: http, ssrs

I have installed SSRS 2014 on a server, and it works fine.
But when a client connects to the server on HTTP/HTTPS, they get a 404 unless they add /Reports to the url.

Is there some way I can add a landing page to SSRS, or do I need to send the user through a load balancer in order to mitigate this behaviour?

Comment: Do you have IIS installed or not?

Comment: There is no IIS installed, SSRS uses its own server

Comment: not sure how to do this unless you have IIS installed.

Comment: not sure how to do this with iis installed, seeing as how ssrs reserves http and https ports.. I can fix it by piping the client through an ARR or netscaler easily enough, but was hoping there was a standard way included with SSRS - seems odd the front page is just a 404.